# Removing the repeating pattern in C++

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I have atleast 16 functions of the following form.

```
bool Node::some_walker( Arg* arg1 )
{   
    if(this == NULL)
       return false;

    bool shouldReturn = false;

    if( this->some_walker_p(arg1, shouldReturn) ) //This line alone varies
        return true;

    if( shouldReturn ) // true is already returned
        return false;

    return this->std_walker(arg1);
}
```

The function some_walker_p is a virtual function and i am not able to templatize it. Is there any solution to avoid this code repetition?

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: You need to give us much, much more information before we can come up with a solution. And why do you think templates are a solution? For (I would estimate) 90% of problems they are not.

Comment: @Gokul: I don's understand your "not able to templatize" remark. In order to avoid the code repetition you's have to templatize various forms of `some_walker` function. The fact that `some_walker_p` is virtual does not interfere with that in any way and makes no difference whatsoever. What is important is whether `some_walker` is virtual. Is it?

Comment: @Andrey: some_walker is not virtual. But let me know, how i can templatize some_walker, when the virtual function call differs for every walker. Thanks.

Comment: if(this == NULL)
I know this works in some cases, but even if it triggers, you are calling a member function on a null pointer, which is undefined.  Better assert and fix the calling code to check for null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether the arguments to the private functions are similar or not. The following solutions are possible, ranging from simple and limited to complex and generic:

1. Equivalent =< Use member-function-pointer)
2. Same number, different types => Templatize over each argument)
3. Different numbers/types of arguments => se boost::bind and function objects)

Thanks for the comments given. At first, I only posted the first solution, but there are (as listed) other situations that need different approaches.

### Member-function-pointer:

```
bool Node::walker_caller(Arg* arg1, bool (Node::*memfn)(Arg*, bool))
{   
    ...
    if( (this->*memfn)(arg1, shouldReturn) ) //This line alone varies
        return true;
    ...
}

bool Node::some_walker(Arg* arg1)
{   
    return walker_caller(arg1, &Node::some_walker_p);
}

bool Node::other_walker(Arg* arg1)
{   
    return walker_caller(arg1, &Node::other_walker_p);
}
```

Sidenote: I usually typedef the mem-fn-ptr to make the syntax more bearable.

### Templated arguments:

I assume you always have two arguments here, but they can have different types.

If you have a limited amount of args-numbers (say 1 and 2), you can could implement walker_caller twice, one impl for one-arg and one for two-arg, both templated.

```
template<class A1, class A2)
bool Node::walker_caller(A1 arg1, A2 arg2, bool (Node::*memfn)(A1, A2, bool))
{   
    ...
    if( (this->*memfn)(arg1, arg2, shouldReturn) ) //This line alone varies
        return true;
    ...
}

bool Node::some_walker(Arg* arg, OtherArg* other_arg)
{   
    return walker_caller(arg, other_arg, &Node::some_walker_p);
}

bool Node::other_walker(OtherArg* other_arg, YetAnotherArg* yaa)
{   
    return walker_caller(other_arg, yaa, &Node::other_walker_p);
}
```

### Function objects:

If your walkers use widely different number and argument types, you probably want to use boost::bind, and maybe  boost::function. (Use of the latter is not required but cuts down on the generated code size...)

```
// faster code, as the function object may be inlined, but
// each call instantiates a different walker_caller, so exe might be bigger
template<class F>
bool Node::walker_caller(const F& fn)
{   
    ...
    if( fn(shouldReturn) ) //This line alone varies
        return true;
    ...
}

// only one implementation, so smaller foot print but
// all arguments need to be copied into a function objet
// which may be a perf hit if the arguments are big
// (this version is good to have when you inherit from Node...)
bool Node::walker_caller(const boost::function<bool (bool)>& fn)
{   
    ...
    if( fn(shouldReturn) ) //This line alone varies
        return true;
    ...
}

bool Node::some_walker(Arg* arg1)
{   
    return walker_caller(boost::bind(&Node::some_walker_p, this, arg1, _1));
}

bool Node::other_walker(Arg* arg1, OtherArg* arg2)
{   
    return walker_caller(boost::bind(&Node::some_walker_p, this, arg1, arg2, _1));
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but only applicable when all the targets have the same function type.

Comment: True. But the OP didn't give much info.

Comment: If the argument count is the same, a `template<typename ArgType> bool Node::walker_caller(ArgType* arg1, bool (Node::*memfn)(ArgType*, bool&)) { ...  if( (this->*memfn)(arg1, shouldReturn) ) return true; ... }` will do fine too and is simplier

Comment: @Johannes: True. There are many variations. I'll add that example too, for completeness. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a (non-virtual) template function which calls a virtual (non-template) function to mimic a templated virtual function. That could help, depending on the structure of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a macro.

I know that get a bad rep, but they have legitimate uses. In general, I think it's more acceptable to use them in your implementation code than in your interface code, so I would consider one here.

```
#define WALKER_MAYBE_DELEGATE( function_name, attempt, fallback, ArgType) \
void Node::function_name(ArgType arg) {\
...
```

Comment: No, we don't want to use macros. But Thanks.